# Hiding error messages in step by step form

Tags: jquery

I'm managed to get the validation working for the *"second step"* and *"third step"*. The problem I'm having now is hiding the error message once the user makes the correct selection. So in effect the user can go back and the message is still there. How can I go about doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/42/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `else` to your validation checks, e.g.

```
if (lower == 1000 && upper == 1000) {
    $("#errorMessage").html('Please select two values other than 1000 and 1000!');
    return false;
} else {
    $("#errorMessage").html(""); // clear error
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/xSkgH/45/)

Answer (score 1):

In think you can put the validation process of each step in separate functions.

Then, you can use it when the user change the value of a field or so... 
And When, the user click on the next|prev link, you can call the right function depending of the step.